# While running ng serve --open in vscode angular 6 i am facing the following issue

Tags: angular

```
$ ng serve --open
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 10% building modules 6/6 modules 0 activei wds: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/
i wds: webpack output is served from /
i wds: 404s will fallback to //index.html

Date: 2020-07-18T11:20:15.355Z
Hash: 0d17336458a8be249934
Time: 12210ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 356 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polytills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 355 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} scyles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 370 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.mep (vendor) 5.5 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,74): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,77): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,52): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,88): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,92): error TS1109: Expression expected.

i wdm: Failed to compile.
```

Please help me to overcome this problem so that i can proceed.

To solve this issue I tried updating the node, cli and npm to the latest versions
but the problem still persists.

Comment: Please don't link to external sites without first describing the problem in depth. Also tell what you tried to solve the same.

Comment: Also tell us the version of Angular you're running.  Also delete node_modules and do a clean npm install, because seeing errors with rxjs like that is odd.

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors. Instead post the code/errors as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). @LakshyaThakur Images at i.stack.imgur.com is not really considered off-site, as it's the only way to add images here.

Comment: I have deleted node modules several times